# Maximum number of concurrent connections jBoss

Tags: performance, apache, tomcat, jboss, mod-jk

We are currently developing a servlet that will stream large image files to a client. We are trying to determine how many Jboss nodes we would need in our cluster with an Apache mod_jk load balancer. I know that it takes roughly 5000 milliseconds to serve a single request. I am trying to use the forumula here http://people.apache.org/~mturk/docs/article/ftwai.html to figure out how many connections are possible, but I am having an issue because they don't explain each one of the numbers in the formula. Specifically they say that you should limit each server to 200 requests per cpu, but I don't know if I should use that in the formula or not. Each server we are using will have 8 cores so I think the forumula should either go like this:

Concurrent Users = (500/5000) * 200 * 8 = 100 concurrent users

Or like this:

Concurrent Users = (500/5000) * (200 * 8) * 8 = ~1200 concurrent users

It makes a big difference which one they meant. Without a example in their documentation it is hard to tell. Could anyone clarify?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess these images aren't static, or you'd have stopped at this line?

> First thing to ease the load from the
>   Tomcat is to use the Web server for
>   serving static content like images,
>   etc..

Even if not, you've got larger issues than a factor of 8: the purpose of his formula is to determine how many concurrent connections you can handle *without the AART (average application response time) exceeding 0.5 seconds*.  Your application takes 5 seconds to serve a single request.  The formula as you're applying it is telling you 9 women can produce a baby in one month.

If you agree that 0.5 seconds is the maximum acceptable AART, then you first have to be able to serve a single request in <=0.5 seconds.

Otherwise, you need to replace his value for maximum AART in ms (500) with yours (which must be greater than or equal to your actual AART).

Finally, as to the question of whether his CPU term should account for cores: it's going to vary depending on CPU & workload.  If you're serving large images, you're probably IO-bound, not CPU-bound.  You need to test.

Max out Tomcat's thread pools & add more load until you find the point where your AART degrades.  That's your actual value for the second half of his equation.  But at that point you can keep testing and see the actual value for "Concurrent Users" by determining when the AART exceeds your maximum.